# BlueOcean - Jenkins not able to pull Docker Image for environment

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to use python image to build and test a very simple python project. But when I give Docker Image name in Jenkinsfile, it fails to pull the image.

```
[drone-python_test-jenk-NVHH77CLU5PUMV6UVRK62EARJB3DUVF5FWILYVRZDXOE54RACN2Q] Running shell script

+ docker pull python

Using default tag: latest

Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

script returned exit code 1
```

JenkinsFile

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'python'
    }  
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '''virtualenv --no-site-packages .env
'''
        sh '.env/bin/pip install -r dev-requirements.txt'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'flake8 setup.py drone tests'
      }
    }
    stage('test2') {
      steps {
        sh 'nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package drone -v'
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**
Tried mounting the docker host using a docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
 jenkins:
   image: jenkinsci/blueocean
   ports:
     - 8888:8080
   volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   restart: always
```

also added user `jenkins` to docker group(is this correct user?)
But it still did not work. DroneIO also used docker images to setup environment but it did not have this issue.

Comment: Do you have docker running on the host you're running Jenkins on?

Comment: I am running Jenkins using a docker image of it.

Comment: Image is `jenkins/blueocean:latest`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.

The Docker daemon inside container seems not started. I started if manually by `docker exec -u root jenkins /bin/sh -c 'dockerd >/var/log/docker.log 2>&1 &'`. It seems to work.

Now, i try to build a Dockerfile that exends `jenkins/blueocean:latest` with a modification af entry point script to start docker daemon automatically.