# Official Docker image of Jenkins fails to create BlueOcean pipeline with another Docker Agent

Tags: docker, jenkins

Following the tutorial at https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/create-a-pipeline-in-blue-ocean/ everything goes fine until the creation of an initial pipeline. The connection to my public GitHub fork of the repository complains that there are no jenkinsfiles in the repo (but they should be there).

I started the docker image this way

```
sudo docker run --rm -u root -p 8080:8080 \
    -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_data \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkinsci/blueocean
```

My suspicion: the internal Docker system is not set up such that it can call back to the Docker host, since there is no Agent entry in the GUI from which I could choose the agent.

[image]

What went wrong?

I tested the advice in [BlueOcean - Jenkins not able to pull Docker Image for environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581998/blueocean-jenkins-not-able-to-pull-docker-image-for-environment), but had no success here.

The Docker machine reports:

```
Apr 10, 2018 2:14:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context log
WARNING: Error while serving http://0.0.0.0:8080/blue/rest/pipeline-metadata/agentMetadata
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:347)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ForwardingFunction.invoke(ForwardingFunction.java:63)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.commons.stapler.TreeResponse$Processor.invoke(TreeResponse.java:43)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
...
```

Comment: I have the same problem both on docker and running the jar file. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I use GitHub now.